# Swift: Help For Json parsing codeable/decodable

Tags: swift, xcode

I am new to iOS, and want to parse the JSON using `Decodable` but cant get through this, how should I work this out?

`The view controller where I am trying to parse the data`

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var servers = [Server]()

    let apiUrl = "https://someurl/api/dashboard"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let url = URL(string: self.apiUrl) else { return }

        getDataFrom(url)
    }

    fileprivate func getDataFrom(_ url: URL) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                let apiResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Server.self, from: data)
                print(apiResponse)
            } catch let jsonError {
                print(jsonError)
            }
            }.resume()
    }


}
```

The `Server.swift` file where I am confirming to the decodable protocol

```swift
struct Server: Decodable {
    let current_page: Int
    let data: [ServerData]
    let first_page_url: String
}

struct ServerData: Decodable {
    let hostname: String
    let ipaddress: String
    let customer: [Customer]
    let latest_value: [LatestValue]
}



struct Customer: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let contact_person :String
    let email: String
}


struct LatestValue: Decodable {
    let systemuptime: String
    let memtotal: Float
    let memfree: Double
    let loadaverage: Float
}
```

`No value associated with key CodingKeys` I get this error,

The response from the server

```php
{
  "servers": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
      {
        "hostname": "johndoes",
        "ipaddress": "10.0.2.99",
        "id": 7,
        "latest_value_id": 1130238,
        "customers": [
          {
            "name": "Jane Doe",
            "contact_person": "John Doe",
            "id": 2,
            "email": "john.@example.com",
            "pivot": {
              "server_id": 7,
              "customer_id": 2
            }
          }
        ],
        "latest_value": {
          "id": 1130238,
          "server_id": 7,
          "systemuptime": "80days:10hours:23minutes",
          "memtotal": 3.7,
          "memfree": 1.6400000000000001,
          "loadaverage": 2.25,
          "disktotal": {
            "dev-mapper-centos-root_disktotal": "38",
            "dev-mapper-proquote-xfs-lvm_disktotal": "200"
          },
          "diskused": "{\"dev-mapper-centos-root_diskused\":\"16\",\"dev-mapper-proquote-xfs-lvm_diskused\":\"188\"}",
          "custom_field": "[]",
          "additional_attributes": {
            "fathom": {
              "name": "fathom",
              "status": 1
            },
            "trenddb": {
              "name": "trenddb",
              "status": 1
            },
            "trendwi": {
              "name": "trendwi",
              "status": 1
            },
            "appsrv": {
              "name": "appsrv",
              "status": 1
            }
          },
          "created_at": "2019-06-15 02:25:02",
          "updated_at": "2019-06-15 02:25:02"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "message": "Success"
}
```

Comment: This issues might be cause you're setying up wrong key. Can you upload response json data from server ?

Comment: @TungVuDuc, can you have a look please I have added the response from the server

Comment: Why you removed the error log, add it again please, It's very helpful for debug

Comment: in `Server` struct have `first_page_url ` property but in repsonse doesn't

Comment: In addition, In response json, it's `servers` not `Server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have few different errors in your data structure.

- First of all, you are trying to decode `Server` while your json has servers inside a dict `{"servers": ... }`, So use a parent root object for it.
- Your `latest_value` inside `ServerData` is defined as array, while it should be `LatestValue` struct not `[LatestValue]`.
- There is no `first_page_url` element in your json, but your `Server` struct has the property, make it optional, so that `JSONDecoder` decodes it only if it is present.

Here is your refined data models.

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let servers: Server
}

struct Server: Decodable {
    let current_page: Int
    let data: [ServerData]
    let first_page_url: String?
}

struct ServerData: Decodable {
    let hostname: String
    let ipaddress: String
    let customers: [Customer]
    let latest_value: LatestValue
}



struct Customer: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let contact_person :String
    let email: String
}


struct LatestValue: Decodable {
    let systemuptime: String
    let memtotal: Float
    let memfree: Double
    let loadaverage: Float
}
```

And decode `Response` instead of decoding `Server`, like so,

```
do {
    let apiResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    let server = apiResponse.server // Here is your server struct.
    print(server)
} catch let jsonError {
    print(jsonError)
}
```